# How to change page heading in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I want to change the titles of page as shown in diagram below.
[image]

How can I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the name of the label in the menu:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  index title: "My custom Title"
end
```

Source: https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#customize-the-namespace

Comment: this not changing label of page

Comment: I've Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use translations to override labels and page titles for actions. You can read more in [docs](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#renaming-action-items)

```
en:
  active_admin:
    resources:
      experience: # Registered resource
        new_model: 'Get new experience'
```